# CMake name of package variables

Tags: cmake

On CMake (version 3.1.1 on OS X Yosemite), the variables set by different packages using `find_package` seem to follow different conventions.

With `find_package(OpenGL)`, the variables `OPENGL_LIBRARY` and `OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR` get set (case-sensitive).

But with `find_package(OpenCV)`, variables with those names remain empty, but `OpenCV_LIBS` get set.

What is the right convention, and is there a way to force CMake to use it, on any platform?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The right conventions are documented [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-developer.7.html#standard-variable-names). For example, a package named `Foo` should make its libraries available in a non-cached `Foo_LIBRARIES` variable and its include directories in a non-cached `Foo_INCLUDE_DIRS` variable.

Because it is entirely up to the maintainer of a CMake find module to follow these conventions, there is no way to enforce them.